# Clearcase config spec : which element will be used when deliver

Tags: clearcase-ucm

using UCM clearcase, assuming i delivered my work from a developer stream into a view in the integration stream and no baseline created and the recomended baseline is not updated.
Assuming that in the config spec an element is selected by Latest version.
When someone new will create a child stream and view from the integration stream, what version  the file will he get?
Will he get the recomended baseline file?
Will he get my file for being the "latest" version?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He/she will get the recommended baseline, which is the default foundation baseline for a child stream.

That child stream could then be rebase with any baseline created on the parent stream, but this is not the case here.

What that child stream will *not* get is the "LATEST" from the parent stream. For that, you would need to create a baseline and recommend it.

Comment: So what is the point with the config_spec? Why and what do we need to explicitly specify elements when we are always being rebase by default from the recomended baseline?

Comment: @user3921 the config_spec is per stream, ie made for one stream: the LATEST is the last versions made on the branch associated to that stream. Those elements have to be selected in the config spec for you to make a checkout based on the latest work done on that stream. It has no bearing on the child stream (which has its own config spec, its own branch, its own LATEST). The child stream is initialized by a fixed foundation baseline coming from the parent stream, ie the one "recommended".